# Accessing Sitecore template field values

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

This may be documented somewhere, but I cannot find it.

I am using the Sitecore helper and razor syntax to place values into my view:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("foo");
```

This works fine, but, I have Fields defined in Groups, and a few of them have the same name, like:

Group1: foo

Group2: foo

Question: Is there any way to access the field by group?
Something like this (what I have already tried):

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Group1.foo");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as I know it is not possible to use the sections name.

I would avoid to have the same field name even between differents sections.

Or a option is to pass the field ID and then create classes or constants to not hard code IDs

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("{E77E229A-2A34-4F03-9A3E-A8636076CBDB}");

or

@Html.Sitecore().Field(MyTemplate.MyGroup.Foo); //where foo returns the id.
```

EDIT:

`MyTemplate.MyGroup.Foo` would be classes/structs you created your own just to make easier and more reliable the references all over you project. (you can use a tool to auto-generate it like a T4 template)

```
public static struct MyTemplate
{
    public static struct MyGroup1
    {
        public static readonly ID Foo = new ID("{1111111-1111-1231-1231-12312323132}");
    }
    public static struct MyGroup2
    {
        public static readonly ID Foo = new ID("{9999999-9999-xxxx-1231-12312323132}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest I avoid having the same name in different sections? I'm not opposed to it, but it seems if there are sections, then logically I should be able to use them this way.

Comment: The section is only to organize data to content authors. They can't be used to find fields. 
Take a look at the Sitecore's Data Definition Reference PDF "2.1.2 Data Template Sections": 
"Fields are always stored 
within a section. Sections, however, are only reflected in the Content Editor. Programmers do not 
need indicate a section when extracting content from a field."

ref: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitionreference-a4.pdf

Comment: Using the Item ID of the field works as both you and Jay S point out. However, I am still unclear what you mean by your second option. I find no overload for the Field method that takes a type of what you describe.

Comment: I updated the answer explaining what I meant by that. It would be only a regular class or struct you create with the ids on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing via the GUID of the field. This way, even if they have the same name, the API will be able to load the appropriate field.